# Oracle SQL Where String Constraint Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have a strange situation where the following (sub)query is throwing a variable window due to the WHERE constraint string.  Is there any way to beat this?  (NOTE: key inputs changed due to proprietary nature of the query)

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) */ x, y AS "SUM PF-07320248 & PF-23456789 NAREA%"
FROM myTable 
WHERE constraintA = 1 AND constraintB LIKE 'abc%' AND constraintC = 'SUM PF-1234678 & PF-23456789'
```

The "& PF" is the part of the WHERE clause that is throwing the variable window, expecting me to enter something.

Comment: That is not a SQL issue, it is an issue with your client interface (SQL\*Plus, or Toad, etc.) I don't know if this works in Toad; in SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer, the way to "fix" this issue (which is that the ampersand is a marker for substitution variables) is to run the following command **before** the query: `set define off`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @mathguy.  This didn't work although it appears supported through Toad 9 or 10.  I'm using 11.

Comment: Using ' || chr(38) || ' in place of the ampersand fixed the problem.